# Unlock Screen When Application is in Background

Tags: android

I have an activity that might by launched when screen is locked. I use this code to make it work:

```
if (powerManager != null) {
            wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                    | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "App:wakeuptag");
            wakeLock.acquire(1000 * 60);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
        } else {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
        }
```

And so far, it works only if application was in foreground before user locked the screen. If application was in bacgkround state before screen was locked, then this code won't work.

Edit: I found out it's not because app is being in background, it's because the app was closed by pressing HOME button, if I close app with back button everything works fine. So, this is somehow relevant with HOME button.